# How can I rewrite this Python code using iteration?

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

The code shown below works. I think using recursion is not effective in Python. How can I convert it to for loop version?

```
def fun(x1, y1, x2, y2, n, r=[]):
    if n<1 :
        return
    r.append( [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]])
    x3=(x1+x2)/2.0
    y3=(y1+y2)/2.0
    fun(x1,y1,x3,y3, n-1)
    fun(x3,y3,x2,y2,n-1)

    x4=(x2+y2-y3-x3)*0.7+x3;
    y4 = (y2 - x2 + x3 - y3)*0.7 + y3;
    fun(x3, y3, x4, y4, n - 1);

    x3 = (3* x1 + x2)/4;
    y3 = (3* y1 + y2)/4;
    x2 = (3*x2 + x1)/4;
    y2 = (3*y2 + y1)/4;
    x4 = (x2*1.7 - y2 + 2*x3 - x3*1.7 + y3)/2;
    y4 = (x2 + y2*1.7 - x3 + 2*y3 - 1.7*y3)/2;
    fun(x3, y3, x4, y4, n - 1);
    return r

print fun(200, 400, 200, 0, 9).__len__()
```

Comment: what is the code trying to do?

Comment: That is certainly a mess. Some documentation about what the purpose of the function is would be helpful.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you are doing, it *might not* be possible to write this iteratively at all. Tail recursion is always translatable to iteration, but you recurse several times throughout the function - and the links between these are non-obvious since you rely on the side effects of a mutable default argument (this also probably makes your code buggy - if you duplicate the last line, it will give a different answer). Writing it iteratively is likely to require a rethink of your entire algorithm, which can't be done without some understanding of what it achieves.

Comment: This code generate data for drawing a tree.

Comment: @lvc, you can still write it iteratively, you just need to explicitly store all the state that you usually leave on the stack. It's not very convenient though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider something like [memoize](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) to speed up recursive functions by using more memory. Essentially it stores the results of any call in a cache.

Add the following code

```
import collections
import functools

class memoized(object):
   '''Decorator. Caches a function's return value each time it is called.
   If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned
   (not reevaluated).
   '''
   def __init__(self, func):
      self.func = func
      self.cache = {}
   def __call__(self, *args):
      if not isinstance(args, collections.Hashable):
         # uncacheable. a list, for instance.
         # better to not cache than blow up.
         return self.func(*args)
      if args in self.cache:
         return self.cache[args]
      else:
         value = self.func(*args)
         self.cache[args] = value
         return value
   def __repr__(self):
      '''Return the function's docstring.'''
      return self.func.__doc__
   def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
      '''Support instance methods.'''
      return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
```

Then decorate your function like this

```
@memoized
def fun(x1, y1, x2, y2, n, r=[]):
    ...
```

Also be careful with your [optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument). The list created by `r = []` will actually be shared across all calls of f with an r. It is better to do something like this so a new list is created every time.

```
def fun(x1, y1, x2, y2, n, r=None):
    r = [] if r is None else r
```

A more Pythonic way of getting the length is like this

```
print len(fun(200, 400, 200, 0, 9))
```

Comment: Along with fixing the list as a default, OP would need to pass `r` in explicitly to the recursive calls, as well as reassign the result of them back to `r`: `r = fun(x1,y1,x3,y3, n-1, r)`. Or, since `r` doesn't figure into any of the calculations, `r.extend(fun(x1,y1,x3,y3,n-1)` which potentially removes the need for `r` to be an argument in the first place.